# Dividing a List into C # Blocks

Tags: c#, list, reorderlist

I have a Branch List, each one has a Number N of employees, I have a Branch object and a NumberEmployees property, now I need to iterate over that list sending the number of employees per block, I explain better with the following table: I order the List by Number of Employees, so far no problem.

```
+---------+-----------+
| Branch  | Employees |
+---------+-----------+
|MEXICO   |     800   |
|USA      |     700   |
|INDIA    |     500   |
|CHINA    |     400   |
|AUSTRALIA|     300   |
+---------+-----------+
```

Now iterate through a list but dividing the number of employees into blocks something like this:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  Branch   | FirstGroup | SecondGroup | ThirdGroup |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Mexico    |        267 |         267 |        267 |
| USA       |        234 |         234 |        234 |
| India     |        167 |         167 |        167 |
| China     |        134 |         134 |        134 |
| Australia |        100 |         100 |        100 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

In the end I think the list that should result would be:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  Branch   | Employees |
+-----------+-----------+
| Mexico    |       267 |
| USA       |       234 |
| India     |       167 |
| China     |       134 |
| Australia |       100 |
| Mexico    |       267 |
| USA       |       234 |
| India     |       167 |
| China     |       134 |
| Australia |       100 |
| Mexico    |       267 |
| USA       |       234 |
| India     |       167 |
| China     |       134 |
| Australia |       100 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

So far I can only order the List.

```
double TotalEmployees = ListBranch.Sum(item => item.EmployeeNumber);
double blockSize = TotalEmployees / ListBranch.Count();
double sizeQuery = Math.Ceiling(blockSize);

                foreach (Branch branch in ListBranch.OrderByDescending(f => f. EmployeeNumber))
{

    //to do
}
```

I appreciate your valuable help for any clues you can give me

Comment: what exactly is the logic for determining how many go in each block?

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
List<BranchEmployee> be = new List<BranchEmployee>();
be.Add(new BranchEmployee() { Branch = "MEXICO", Employee = 800 });
be.Add(new BranchEmployee() { Branch = "USA", Employee = 700 });
be.Add(new BranchEmployee() { Branch = "INDIA", Employee = 500 });
be.Add(new BranchEmployee() { Branch = "CHINA", Employee = 400 });
be.Add(new BranchEmployee() { Branch = "AUSTRALIA", Employee = 300 });
List<BranchEmployee> ExpectedBE = new List<BranchEmployee>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    foreach(BranchEmployee smbe in be)
    {
        ExpectedBE.Add(new BranchEmployee()
        {
            Branch = smbe.Branch,
            Employee = smbe.Employee / 3
        });
    }
}
```

What I see is that every group has equal number of employees that is the total number of employees divided by 3.

To look the data in the way you have shown I have created a class like this

```
public class BranchEmployee
{
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public int Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you would give me an example of how to do it on the same list, ie on the initial list? And I do not understand the purpose of the For.